# Appium:How can I search an element using regex

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium

I am using Appium for automating my desktop WPF application (build in C# .Net).
My automation is idenitfying the WPF application window by its name , which is dynamic. For ex: The application window name is "ABC1.0.0" Where ABC will be constant but 1.0.0, which is the version, will vary.
Currently if I hardcode the name to "ABC1.0.0" then findelementbyname works and window gets identified but I just wanted to check if there a way to use regular expression to identify my window without hardcoding ? Note: Xpath wont work for our desktop app.
For ex: Something like this:
FindElementByName("ABC.*")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is get an element which contains "ABC.".

Should look like so.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(text(),\'ABC.\')]"));
```

Comment: text() rather than @text